# O que significa 1e+24 console chrome?

Tags: javascript, matemática, console, números

Reparei que quando digito no console do chrome `1000000000000000000000000` ele me retorna `1e+24`.

E quando digito `1000000000000000009901591` ele também me retorna `1e+24` sendo que `1000000000000000000000000` é diferente de `1000000000000000009901591`

1. Porque isso acontece?
2. E como diferenciar os dois?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Isso é uma representação exponencial. Não é possível diferenciar os dois pois esses números extrapolam a precisão máxima do tipo numérico usado pelo javascript, que é por baixo dos panos um tipo `double` da norma IEEE 754.

A representação exponencial funciona assim:

**M**e+**E** => M × 10<sup>E</sup>

**M**e-**E** => M × 10<sup>-E</sup>

Para o número indicado, temos M = 1, e E = 24 positivo. Então o valor final será:

1 × 10<sup>24</sup>, ou seja, 1 seguido de 24 zeros.

Comment: No caso, o Chrome usa o `V8` e é possível confirmar o `double` que o Miguel Angelo disse pela documentação: http://izs.me/v8-docs/classv8_1_1Number.html

Comment: Note que esta norma (IEEE 754, utilizada pela maioria dos processadores) não permite especificar mais de 17 algarismos significativos. E o 17º muitas vezes já é um arredondamento.