# Calculo de multiplicação incorreto

Tags: php

Por algum motivo quando realizo o calculo múltiplicando por um valor flutuante o PHP sempre me retorna o valor errado.

Exemplo:

```
echo ((33 * 0.8) - 26.4);

result: 3.5527136788005E-15
```

Porém o resultado esperado seria `0`

Não consegui encontrar nenhuma resposta para esse problema, pois se eu realizar o calculo para pegar 80% do valor de forma diferente funciona.

Exemplo:

```
echo (((33 * 80) / 100) - 26.4);

result: 0
```

Comment: Comece lendo a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.float.php). Ela explica bem porque isso acontece.

Comment: Talvez possa te ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13128769/simple-math-with-decimals-in-php

Comment: se mesmo assim quer usar 0.8 então use assim echo number_format(((33 * 0.8) - 26.4),0)  e se precisar de 2 casas decimas use echo number_format(((33 * 0.8) - 26.4),2)

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss eu queria saber também o motivo disso acontecer também, simplesmente é apenas um calculo qualquer, porém quando é decimal pela porcentagem retorna esse valor

Comment: Testa http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/188514/3635 e me avisa.

Comment: Nota do moderador: apesar de a pergunta vinculada como duplicata estar marcada com a tag JavaScript, o problema (e a resposta) é universal para qualquer linguagem no uso de números de ponto flutuante.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo, dando como number_format funciona perfeitamente, porém gostaria de saber o motivo do php dá esse resultado invez do 0

Comment: @bfavaretto eu tinha reaberto pois ele quer saber como "resolver", inclusive eu tinha linkado todas estas na primeira vez que marquei como dup, mas concordo contigo, de qualquer forma quis deixar uma resposta, só não sei se é a melhor solução para PHP.

Comment: Muito obrigado a todos, era mais para saber o motivo, pois até então nunca tinha visto algo igual.

Comment: Só para confirmar, você percebeu que `3.5527136788005E-15` é praticamente zero, certo?

Comment: Sim, mas sempre quando comparava com o valor correto retornava `false`, da outra forma que citei no exemplo funciona perfeitamente.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Como você já possui a resposta de como contornar a situação, deixarei aqui o trecho da [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.float.php) que explica o porquê disso acontecer.

> #### Precisão de números de ponto flutuante
>
> Números de ponto flutuante tem precisão limitada. Embora dependa do sistema, o PHP geralmente utiliza o formato de precisão dupla do IEEE 754, que trará uma precisão máxima devida a arredondamentos da ordem de 1.11e-16. Operações matemáticas incomuns poderão ocasionar erros maiores, e, claro, a propagação de erros deve ser considerada quando várias operações forem realizadas.
>
> Além disso, números racionais que tem representação exata em números em base 10, como 0.1 ou 0.7, não possuem representação exata em ponto flutuante na base 2, o formato utilizado internamente, não importando o tamanho da mantissa. Portanto não existe conversão para o formato interno sem uma pequena perda de precisão. Isso pode ocasionar resultados confusos: por exemplo, floor((0.1+0.7)*10) normalmente retornará 7, em vez do resultado esperado 8, porque a representação interna final será algo como 7.9999999999999991118....
>
> Então, nunca confie em resultados com números de ponto flutuante até a última casa, e nunca compare números de ponto flutuante em igualdades. Se você realmente precisar de alta precisão, você pode utilizar as [funções matemáticas de precisão arbitrária](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.bc.php) e as funções [gmp](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.gmp.php) estão disponíveis.
>
> Para uma explicação "simples" dessa questão, veja o [» guia sobre ponto flutuante](http://floating-point-gui.de/), que também tem o título alternativo de "Porque meus números não somam direito?".

Comment: pois é echo number_format((0.1 + 0.2),22); tá dando 0.3000000000000000444089

Answer (score 4):

A resposta do [Anderson](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/188492/3635) explica o porque, assim como estas perguntas:

- [O que significa 1e+24 console chrome?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11295/3635)
- [Resultado impreciso em cálculo com números quebrados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5642/3635)
- [Qual é o máximo de casas decimais permitidas no float em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136808/3635)

Então para tentar ajustar você pode usar a função `round`, isto irá arredondar o valor, assim:

```
$foo = (33 * 0.8) - 26.4;

echo round($foo);
```

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Ajuste o segundo parâmetro conforme a precisão que deseja:

```
$foo = (33 * 0.8) - 26.4;

echo round($foo, 3);
```

Answer (score 3):

Uma das formas fácies de contornar isto é utilizar o `BC Math`.

Dessa forma o `((33 * 0.8) - 26.4)` seria:

```
bcscale(2);
echo bcsub(bcmul('33', '0.8'), '26.4');

// O resultado será de `0.00`.
```

[Teste isto.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ea1ad8930760c33a6c35c7aed5162e03b1071f16)

O `bcsub()` irá subtrair o `26.4` do valor resultante do `bcmul()`. O `bcmul()` é responsável por multiplicar o `33` por `0.8`, contendo 2 dígitos *após a virgula*, definido pelo`bcscale(2);`, neste caso.

> Na ausência da definição do `bcscale` será utilizado o padrão 0, tornando 5.7 - 4.3 = 1, ao invés de `1.4`, por exemplo.

---

Se quiser comparar valores pode utilizar o `bccomp()`, ele funciona de maneira similar ao [*operador nave-espacial*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30365346/what-is-the-spaceship-operator-in-php-7) (`<=>`), onde retorna `0` se for igual, `-1` o lado esquerdo for maior ou `1` se o lado direito for maior, [Teste isto](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/304e93c02bb77995b43460d4338f68f899b1e1e7).

```
echo bccomp(bcmul('33', '0.8', 2), '26.4', 2);

// O resultado será de `0`.
```

Toda a documentação do `bc*` está em http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.bc.php, como indicado pelo [@Anderson Carlos Woss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5878/anderson-carlos-woss).