# Erro de arredondamento

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde!

Tenho a seguinte função js que que retorna os novos valores do carrinho quando a quantidade do produto é alterada:

```
  function add(_quant, _preco, _total, _estoque) {
      quantidade = parseInt($("#"+_quant).val());
      estoque = parseInt($("#"+_estoque).val());
      preco = parseFloat($("#"+_preco).val());

      idCampo = _quant.substring(10, _quant.lenght);

      novaQuantidade = quantidade + 1;

      if(novaQuantidade <= estoque) {         
          if(novaQuantidade == 0) {
              alert("Quatidade não por ser 0");
          } else {
              total = novaQuantidade * preco;                 
              $("#"+_quant).val(novaQuantidade) ;
              $("#"+_total).html(total.toFixed(2));

              $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "_required/sessaoCarrinho.php",
                   data: {idProduto:idCampo, novaQuantidade: novaQuantidade},
                   dataType: 'json'
                  }).done(function(response){
                     subTotal = response['subTotal'];
                     $(".subTotal").html(subTotal.toFixed(2));            
                     $(".totalCarrinhoTopo").html(subTotal.toFixed(2));
              });


          }
      }  else {
              alert("Quantidade escolhida maior que estoque");
      }
  }
```

Acontece que esse calculo está dando erro de arredondamento,

o que fazer?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Possível duplicata: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5642

Comment: Me perdoe, não vejo como duplicata pois as respostas apresentam a explicação e não apresentam uma solução! No caso, estou buscando a solução. Se é que ela existe!

Comment: Esta [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/10966/5878) parece resolver seu problema, não?

Comment: Não Anderson, o resultado deu o mesmo. Ou seja, 37,71 * 2 = 63,41 ao invés se 63,42. Entende?

Comment: Veja no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/E5MdrU) e no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/GQhE/0). Ambos deram 63,42 como resposta. No navegador continua 63,41?

Comment: Você me abriu os olhos para outra coisa: vou conferir o retorno php do ajax. Daí, posto a resposta!

Comment: Pois é, no PHP existe o mesmo problema. Veja [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/188486).

Comment: O problema era mesmo no js. Problema resolvido Obrigado! Apenas fiz total = novaQuantidade * parseFloat(preco.toFixed(2));

Answer (score 0):

Tente fazer um replace da virgula por ponto no campo preço antes de converter para float. Como fiz abaixo.

```
function add(_quant, _preco, _total, _estoque) {
  quantidade = parseInt($("#"+_quant).val());
  estoque = parseInt($("#"+_estoque).val());
  preco = parseFloat($("#"+_preco).val().replace(",","."));

  idCampo = _quant.substring(10, _quant.lenght);

  novaQuantidade = quantidade + 1;

  if(novaQuantidade <= estoque) {         
      if(novaQuantidade == 0) {
          alert("Quatidade não por ser 0");
      } else {
          total = novaQuantidade * preco;                 
          $("#"+_quant).val(novaQuantidade) ;
          $("#"+_total).html(total.toFixed(2));

          $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "_required/sessaoCarrinho.php",
               data: {idProduto:idCampo, novaQuantidade: novaQuantidade},
               dataType: 'json'
              }).done(function(response){
                 subTotal = response['subTotal'];
                 $(".subTotal").html(subTotal.toFixed(2));            
                 $(".totalCarrinhoTopo").html(subTotal.toFixed(2));
          });


      }
  }  else {
          alert("Quantidade escolhida maior que estoque");
  }
```

}