# Conversao de inteiro na conta arredondamento 0.1

Tags: php, lógica

`echo (int) ((0.1 + 0.7) * 10 )`

Pela logica isso não deveria retornar 8? 
0.1 + 0.7 = 0.8 * 10 = 8

Esta me retornando 7. porque?

Comment: Pessoal me perdoem por estar "repetida", mas  estava com duvida nessa equação que passei a voces, os exemplos aqui citados como duplicados, são bem mais complexos que o meu, sou leigo em, php seria meio complicado eu entender que meu problema se iguala a estes citados, obrigado pela ajuda de todos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por padrão o PHP usa números de [ponto flutuante](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ponto_flutuante), nesse caso específico você pode conseguir o valor correto através do arredondamento, utilizando [`round`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.round.php) ou utilizar outro tipo como: `float`, `double`.

```
echo (int) round((0.1 + 0.7) * 10);
```

Acontece que 0,1 + 0,7 não é exatamente 0,8 e sim 7,99999... E no momento que é convertido para `int` o resultado gerado é 7

Answer (score 2):

A matemática de ponto flutuante não funciona perfeitamente como esperamos, olha:

```js
console.log(0.1 + 0.7)
```

Se você executar esse snippet, o resultado será 0.799999....

Converter esse número pra inteiro causa o arredondamento para baixo:

```js
console.log(parseInt(0.1 + 0.7))
```

Esse outro trecho mostra simplesmente 0. Porque 0.79999 arredondado para baixo é 0.

Porém, você multiplicou por 10 antes de converter para inteiro, isso arredondou 7.99999... para baixo, que é 7.

Se quiser saber um pouco mais sobre esse comportamento estranho, você pode dar uma olhada [nessa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) excelente resposta do SO em inglês, ou [nesse](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) outro link. (Procurarei links em português para postar aqui.)

PS: Eu sei que a pergunta dele é em PHP, mas acredito que esse comportamento é comum do Javascript também, então serve de exemplo, corrijam-me se forem diferentes ou se eu estiver errado

Comment: Downvoter, pode comentar?

Comment: Provavelmente foi por não ser em PHP mesmo. Tente evitar isso se o autor da pergunta não cita em momento algum outra linguagem. Se o autor tivesse colocado algo como "tive esse problema em PHP e vi que acontece o mesmo no JS" sua resposta seria válida. Como o foco era só PHP, sua resposta não se encaixa com a pergunta. Eu acho válido fazer isso, desde que já no início da resposta você deixe claro que o problema é independente de linguagem, que não foi o caso.

Comment: Muito obrigado @AndersonCarlosWoss

Answer (score 1):

Acho que esta pergunta seja [duplicada desta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/188486/calculo-de-multiplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-incorreto/188492), que por si também é duplicada de outras, porém o fato da representação ser `8`, mesmo em float, pode enganar.

Quando você dar um:

```
echo ((0.1 + 0.7) * 10);
```

Você tem como resultado o `8`, porém se fizer isto:

```
if(((0.1 + 0.7) * 10) === 8e0){
    echo 'Este valor é 8';
}
```

Verá que este valor é uma mentira, não é o `if` que está errado, pode tentar até usando `== 8`, o problema é que o calculo por si não resulta em 8.

Se você executar:

```
var_export(((0.1 + 0.7) * 10));
```

Verá o seu verdadeiro valor, `7.999999999999999`, que é diferente de oito.

Por essa razão fazer isto:

```
echo (int)7.999999999999999
```

Resultará em `7`, pois é "equivalente" a fazer um `floor(7.999999999999999)`.

Isto está explicado, inclusive com os mesmos valores [na documentação](http://php.net/language.types.float) e [também esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/188492/15089).

---

Uma solução para o problema é utilizar o BCMath ou GMP.

```
bcscale(2);

echo bcmul(bcadd('0.1', '0.7'), '10');
```

O `bcadd` irá somar `0.1` com `0.7` e o `bcmul` irá multiplicar o resultado do `bcadd` (`0.8`) com o `10`.