# Por que no Python 0.03 % 0.01 = 0.009999999999999998 e não 0?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ponto-flutuante

```
>>> 0.03 % 0.01
0.009999999999999998
```

Por que dá este resultado, sendo que o resto da divisão é 0?

E também, ao invés de 3, dar:

```
>>> 0.03 // 0.01
2.0
```

Comment: Leia estas referências: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14763891/7690982), [2](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4432208/7690982) e [4](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/decimal.html). Principalmente nas refs das respostas dadas aqui.

Comment: Não só no Python, mas como em qualquer linguagem de programação que use pontos flutuantes da norma IEEE 754

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Exatamente pelo mesmo motivo que 0.1 + 0.7 é 0.7999999999999999 e não 0.8.

- [Resultado impreciso em cálculo com números quebrados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5642/5878)
- [Calculo de multiplicação incorreto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/188486/5878)
- [Conversao de inteiro na conta arredondamento 0.1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/204735/5878)

Que, resumidamente resume-se ao resumo: [IEEE 754](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).

Para contornar o problema, você precisa utilizar o módulo [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/decimal.html):

```
from decimal import Decimal

a = Decimal('0.03')
b = Decimal('0.01')

print(a % b)  # 0.00
print(a // b)  # 3
```

Answer (score 12):

> **Resposta curta:** Problemas de precisão em operações de vírgula flutuante.

---

Os números decimais são representados no computador como fracções decimais. Por exemplo, `0.125(10) = 0.001(2)`. Nada de novo - mas se o for, dê uma vista de olhos a este [pequeno resumo na Wikipédia sobre vírgula flutuante](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/V%C3%ADrgula_flutuante).

O problema é quando entramos em números que não conseguem ser descritos de forma fácil por uma fracção binária em que resultam em dízimas infinitas como o caso do `1/3 = 0.33(3)` no sistema decimal.

Os computadores não possuem um número infinito de bits pelo que usam representações aproximadas dos números que pretendem representar. São apresentações bastante próximas mas continuam a não ser o número em questão.

```
>>> 0.1
0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
```

O Python (entre outras linguagens) conseguem detetar estes casos e apresentam ao utilizador uma representação "arredondada" ao utilizador que corresponde ao que seria esperado:

```
>>> 1 / 10
0.1
```

No entanto isto não muda o valor que está na memória. Como tal, ao fazer `0.03 % 0.01` não está *mesmo* a fazer o resto da divisão de 0.03 por 0.01 mas sim o resto da divisão da representação em memória de 0.03 por 0.01, resultando no erro que vê:

```
>>> 0.03 % 0.01
0.009999999999999998
```

**Fonte:** [O Tutorial de Python - Operações aritméticas de vírgula flutuante: problemas e limitações](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) (*em Inglês*)