# Por que fractions.Fraction(1/3) não retorna "1/3"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import fractions
a = int(input())
b = 1 / a
b = fractions.Fraction(b)
print(b)
```

Essa é uma parte de um código que estou desenvolvendo. Essa parte tinha a função de pegar o decimal resultante da divisão "1 / a" e transformá-la em fração e aparentemente não esta funcionando.
Ex:

input = 3

b = 1 / 3 = 0.333

b = 1/3 (Output desejado)

Mas o output que recebo com esse exemplo é "6004799503160661/18014398509481984". Sei que essa é uma fração equivalente mas a fração "1/3" já seria suficiente.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1/3 é uma dízima periódica; isto é, a quantidade de 3 após a vírgula é infinita, o que faz com que seja impossível representá-la computacionalmente. Quando você armazena o valor em memória, o valor será truncado conforme a arquitetura que está utilizando, assim, a representação em fração deixa de ser 1/3.

Perceba que a incoerência fica bem explícita até no seu exemplo, onde diz que "1 / 3 = 0.333". Matematicamente, 1/3 vale 0.33333333333..., não apenas 0.333. São números diferentes, com frações geratrizes diferentes.

Mas o ponto principal é: por que dividir antes de gerar a fração?

Ao ler a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/fractions.html) verá que `Fraction` recebe dois parâmetros: o numerador e o denominador. Isto é, basta fazer:

```
import fractions

a = int(input())
b = fractions.Fraction(1, a)

print(b)
```

Se entrar com o valor 3, a saída será 1/3.

Perceba que o mesmo problema acontece em outros valores, mesmo que não gerem uma dízima periódica. Por exemplo, no seu código, se entrar com o valor 5, que deveria gerar o valor 0.2 e, consequentemente, retornar a fração 1/5 retorna, de fato, 3602879701896397/18014398509481984. Isso porque, semelhante ao que foi comentado acima, o valor 1/5 também não é pode ser representado como ponto flutuante. O valor que parece 0.2 na verdade é um valor muito próximo a ele, o que faz com que a fração gerada seja diferente do esperado.

Para mais detalhes, ler:

- [Resultado impreciso em cálculo com números quebrados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5642/5878)
- [Por quê no Python 0.03 % 0.01 = 0.009999999999999998 e não 0?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/309882/5878)

Comment: Verifiquei aqui, e realmente é esse o problema, divisões que não retornam dizimas ficam em sua forma simplificada. Sei que 1/3 = 0.333... kkkkk. Utilizei a estrutura que você recomendou e deu certo, muito obrigado.

Ps: Nunca tinha utilizado esse módulo antes, estou aprendendo a usá-lo ainda.

Comment: @GustavoMatias então recomendo que leia a documentação antes de continuar.