# Progressão Aritmética em Python com números decimais

Tags: python-3.x

Estava fazendo uns exercícios na Internet e me deparei com o seguinte: criar um programa que leia o primeiro termo e a razão e calcule o enésimo termo dessa P.A. Fiz o programa mas fiquei na dúvida "e se eu inserisse um número decimal no lugar da razão ou do primeiro termo?".

```
a1 = int(input('Insira o valor do primeiro termo: '))
r = int(input('Insira o valor da razão: '))
pa = a1 + (9 * r)
for c in range(a1, pa, r):
    print(c)
```

O problema está em substituir o "int" por "float". Recebo este erro:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "c:/Users/ricar/Desktop/curso-python/teste/testes.py", line 4, in 
>       for c in range(a1, pa, r):
>   TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim, basta utilizar o `float`. A questão é que você não precisa utilizar o `range` para calcular todos os termos da sequência apenas para saber o n-ésimo termo. Imagina se for solicitado o 1.000.000.000º termo da progressão?

Para progressões aritméticas é sabido que o n-ésimo termo pode ser obtido através de

a<sub>n</sub> = a<sub>1</sub> + (n-1)*r

sendo a<sub>1</sub> o primeiro termo e r a razão.

Assim, bastaria fazer:

```py
a1 = float(input('Primeiro termo: '))
r = float(input('Razão: '))
n = int(input('N: '))

an = a1 + (n-1)*r

print(f'O {n}º termo da PA é {an}')
```

A estrutura `range` funciona apenas com inteiros pois todo seu comportamento está baseado em somas e comparações entre valores. A partir do valor inicial incrementa-se o valor de passo enquanto for menor que o valor final. Para números com ponto flutuante isso se torna crítico porque essas operações podem resultar em valores *inesperados*, dadas as limitações do sistema de representá-los. Para mais informações veja:

- [Por que no Python 0.03 % 0.01 = 0.009999999999999998 e não 0?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/309882/5878)

Comment: Não tinha ideia de que a estrutura 'range' funciona apenas com números inteiros. Obrigado pelo esclarecimento.