# Por que (0.1 + 0.2 - 0.3) é 5.55111512313e-17?

Tags: python, float, arquitetura-computadores

Parece bem óbvio para nós humanos que **0.1 + 0.2 - 0.3** é **0** mas por que quando peço para o interpretador do Python realizar a seguinte operação:

```
print(0.1 + 0.2 - 0.3)
```

ele retorna **5.55111512313e-17**?

É algo relacionado com a precisão dos floats?

Comment: Tens várias perguntas/respostas aqui no site acerca disso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5642, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/219211 , https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38138 ...

Comment: Relacionada: [Por que no Python 0.03 % 0.01 = 0.009999999999999998 e não 0?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/309882)

Comment: Obrigado @Miguel, estava na dúvida se fechava como duplicata, mas tem vários exemplos aqui falando sobre o IEEE 754.